# Defining a priority when using multiple IOperationBehavior attributes

Tags: .net, wcf

Consider the following IOperationBehavior attributes:

```
public class OperationCredentialsAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
}

public class OperationProcessesAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
}
```

... and the following operation definition:

```
public interface IService
{
    [OperationCredentials(true)]
    [OperationProcesses(new[] { "CreateCustomerProcess" })]
    CreateCustomerResponse CreateCustomer(CreateCustomerMessage CreateCustomerMessage);
}
```

I need to make sure that the OperationCredentials attribute is processed before the OperationProcesses attribute since both are using the ApplyDispatchBehavior method to register custom invokers and the execution order is important.

From my tests the decoration order is not always the order in what they are processed when the service loads.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question that I unfortunately have no idea how to answer. Did you find out the answer?

Comment: No I didn't. I had to merge the two attributes into one and enforce the order right there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your solution to merge the attributes into one was the correct one.

This article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730137.aspx) discusses the precedence of the various extension mechanisms, and states that:

> Within any collection of behaviors, again, no order is guaranteed.

Where a collection might be a set of IOperationBehaviors defined on a method.